# Installing Axis to Tomcat container

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-axis, axis

I have a problem in installing Axis 1 to Tomcat, I've installed my Apache at `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64` ,  I copied and pasted `DIRECTORY\axis-1_4\webapps`'s folder `axis` to `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.64` as per some examples I followed earlier, when I tried to start tomcat server, it starts normally but it seems axis hasn't been deployed, I researched a little bit, it seems that I have to deploy a war file, but I could find it in the installation directory.

Any thoughts regarding this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Axis 1 is outdated (2006), you should consider to use Axis 2 and follow this guide http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html#servlet_container.

Anyway, in your Tomcat `webapps` directory you should have either a WAR or an `axis` directory which represents the unzipped WAR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)